# Error al instalar php 7,2 en ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, php7

Sucede que tengo un servidor **`ubuntu`** **16.04** con **php 7.0**, pero requiero instalar la **versión 7.2** de **`php`**, pero al intentar hacer esto sucede que la instalación se cancela y me saca el siguiente error:

> root@server:/etc/apt# sudo apt-get install php7.2
>       Reading package lists... Done
>       Building dependency tree
>       Reading state information... Done
>       You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>       The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>        ghostscript : Depends: libgs9 (= 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.11) but 
>        9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.9 is to be installed
>        php7.2 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.2 but it is not going to be installed or
>                      php7.2-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
>                      php7.2-cgi but it is not going to be installed
>        php7.2-common : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
>        E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

No me deja instalar ni las dependencias ni **php**, y no encuentro documentación acerca de este error, alguna idea?

Comment: Suena a que en el sistema hay paquetes dañados o incompatibles con la instalación que quieres hacer. Mira este caso similar: [Can't use apt-get due to unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970164/cant-use-apt-get-due-to-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que tenia un error en la dependencia del paquete de la versión anterior, tenia una extraña mezcla de paquetes entre la versión 14.04 y 16.04, me aparecían paquetes de una versión de linux que actualice hace 2 años, no se como ocurrio pero cuando intente re instalar php 7.2 salio error de la dependencia de los paquetes, todos los comando apt-get estaban condenados a fallar, y aparecia el error superior.

Al intentar hacer **apt-get -f install** no hacia por el mismo error en dependencia, buscando un poco mas d e documentación, y luego de intentar resolver los errores de dependencia manualmente (lo que fue una terrible idea), encontre una respuesta que funciona para mi.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

No fue mi solución, si tienen dudas por favor revisen esta otra [respuesta](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067814/upgrade-solve-dependency-on-previous-release-package)